# How to BiCluster with constant values in columns - in R

Tags: r

My Problem in general: 
I have a data frame where i would like to find all bi-clusters with constant values in columns.
For Example the initial dataframe:

```
> df

  v1 v2 v3

1  0  2  1
2  1  3  2
3  2  4  3
4  3  3  4
5  4  2  3
6  5  2  4
7  2  2  3
8  3  1  2
```

And for example i would like to find the a cluster like this:

```
> cluster1
  v1 v3
1  2  3
2  2  3
```

I tried to use the biclust package and tested several functions but the result was always not what i want to archive.

I figured out that I may can use the BCPlaid function with fit.model = y ~ m. But it looks like this produce also different results.

Is there a way to archive this task efficient?